# Regex to validate that a string contains only 0 - 9, +, #, *, [ and ]

Tags: c#, regex, string, validation

In my c# application, I need to validate strings to ensure that they only contain the following:

- 0 - 9
- +
- #
- *
- [
- ]

When my user edits a string field in the cell of a DataGridView control, I need to validate the value.  My CellValidating event handler currently looks like this:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), @"\A\b[0-9]+\b\Z"))
{
    // notify the user that the string is invalid and cancel validation
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This seems to work for 0 - 9 but I've yet to get a regex working that includes all the metacharacters I need.  I tried adding one metacharacter at a time to the existing regex but it doesn't work.  For example...

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), @"\A\b[0-9#]+\b\Z"))
```

...doesn't allow # like I thought it would.  Escaping it didn't make a difference either.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: The word boundary markers (`\b`) are going to cause problems, because most of your metacharacters don't count as part of a "word".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this regex `^[0-9+#*\[\]]+$`